# Using MPMediaPickerController with Flutter

Tags: ios, dart, flutter

I'm playing with Dart and Flutter and would like to display a media picker inside my Flutter application.

The Flutter part of my application simply has a button which calls platform specific code. I don't believe this part causes the problem so I'm not adding it. If asked, I'll edit my question.

Here is the Objective-C part of my application:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    FlutterViewController *controller = (FlutterViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    FlutterMethodChannel *audioPlayerChannel = [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"com.myapp.plugin/audio" binaryMessenger:controller];

    [audioPlayerChannel setMethodCallHandler:^(FlutterMethodCall * _Nonnull call, FlutterResult  _Nonnull result) {
        if ([call.method isEqualToString:@"showMediaPicker"]) {
            [self _showMediaPicker];

            result(@0);
        }
        else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
        }
    }];

    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)_showMediaPicker {
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    MCMediaPickerViewController *delegate = [[MCMediaPickerViewController alloc] init];
    FlutterViewController *controller = (FlutterViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    [picker setDelegate:delegate];
    [picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems:NO];

    [controller presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

The class `MCMediaPickerViewController` simply implements the `MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

When I run this code on my device and press the button, a blank controller appears and disappears right after, without displaying the picker. Any idea why this happens?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue isn't related to flutter.

Try to add [NSAppleMusicUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW47) to Info.plist. After this iOS will start asking user about permissions.

Comment: It was that! Thank you very much!